# Overriding "defun" within a package

Tags: package, lisp, common-lisp, symbols, parenscript

I would like to define a macro named "defun" from within a package i am creating and i would like to export it to be used in certain places. There is a library called parenscript that does this in it's package like so,

```
(export #:defun)
```

When i try to do this within my own package i get this SBCL error

```
Lock on package COMMON-LISP violated when defining DEFUN as a macro while in package COMMON-LISP-USER.
```

How is this done in the parenscript library? I know that you can type the form;

```
(ps (defun function-name (args) (body)))
```

I want to be able to do the same but cannot figure out how this is done?

Comment: They might use `ps` as a macro that defines its own bindings, working around SBCL's restrictions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to shadow the original symbol from the CL package.

```
CL-USER 1 > (defpackage "MY-PACKAGE" (:use "CL"))
#<The MY-PACKAGE package, 0/16 internal, 0/16 external>

CL-USER 2 > (in-package "MY-PACKAGE")
#<The MY-PACKAGE package, 0/16 internal, 0/16 external>

MY-PACKAGE 3 > (shadow 'defun)
T

MY-PACKAGE 4 > (cl:defun defun () :my-defun-returns)
DEFUN

MY-PACKAGE 5 > (defun)
:MY-DEFUN-RETURNS

MY-PACKAGE 6 > (export 'defun)
T
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to read more about [packages and symbols](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/programming-in-the-large-packages-and-symbols.html). Here I am going to qualify all symbols when needed so that there is no ambiguity about which one I am talking about.

1. You cannot redefine `CL:DEFUN`, this invokes undefined behavior and you are likely to "break" your runtime by making it unusable. That's why SBCL has a concept of *locks* for packages, which are a way to avoid modifying a package and its bindings by mistake (you can still unlock a package, by you usually don't need to).
2. Under the scope of your macro, you are free to interpret `CL:DEFUN` as you wish, which is what Parenscript does by translating a subset of actual Lisp code to Javascript.
3. In any other package `P`, you can define `P:DEFUN` as a variable/function/macro/whatever that is entirely distinct from `CL:DEFUN`. You can export it and everything is fine, you can use both `P:DEFUN` and `CL:DEFUN` however you want.
4. Conflicts can happen if you want to write an unqualified `DEFUN` symbol and have the reader find out which symbols is being referenced. Typically, users of a library might define a package like so:

   ```
   (defpackage :foo (:use :cl :p))
   ```

   This leads to a conflict, because both the "CL" and the "P" packages export "DEFUN". One way to solve that is to define a Common Lisp dialect that rebind `DEFUN` and re-exports all other symbols from "CL". Your users must then use only your package and not the CL one. Another way is to *use* CL and *shadow-import* only "DEFUN" from P, so that `DEFUN` is an alias for `P:DEFUN` (consequently, you *need* to write `CL:DEFUN` to explicitly reference the Common Lisp macro).

The link given above goes into more details.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So is it safe to say that parenscript does some form of code-walking on CL code to perform it's compilation? That must be the only way surely

Comment: @JamesGunn Yes: see https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/parenscript/parenscript/blob/master/src/compiler.lisp#L318